# RSpec and Testing Command Line Args Passed to Script

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm some rspec tests for a command line ruby based application.  I'm trying to build my test suite allow for testing of missing command line parameters.  Specifically, I'd like to stub out what ARGV[0]..ARGV[N] would appear to the application.  I've seen similar posts mention ENV.stub; however, I don't see how I can simulate "nameless" args and a given order.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I simply did this in my test case located in `spec`:

```
it "does something" do
  arg = "/tmp"
  exe = File.expand_path('../bin/site_checker', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("#{exe} -Ilib #{arg}")
  stdout.readlines.should be_empty
end
```